# Hazelcast Python

Tags: python, hazelcast, event-listener, hazelcast-imap

I am totally new to this hazelcast. Is there any way to monitor the events/ event listeners for hazelcast in python. I have added my code below, how to create event listeners for this

```
hz_map = client.get_map("auth-map").blocking()

hz_map.set("key", "value")

print(hz_map.get("key"))
```

Comment: And also how to set ttl for expiry

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to listen to entry events in the Python client.

You can add a listener with a code similar to the one below.

```py
def added_func(event):
    print("Entry Added: %s-%s" % (event.key, event.value))


hz_map = client.get_map("auth-map").blocking()

hz_map.add_entry_listener(include_value=True, added_func=added_func)

hz_map.set("key", "value")

print(hz_map.get("key"))
```

You can see a more detailed explanation regarding other possible events and methods in https://hazelcast.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_python_client_with_hazelcast.html#listening-for-map-events

Note that, your event handlers (functions like `added_func`) should be non-blocking and short-lived. If you are going to do a blocking operation or a long-running one in those event handlers, you better be offloading that task to a separate thread.

For TTL, you can specify it in the set method.

```py
hz_map.set("key", "value", ttl=5)
```